# submit values using partial view to database mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

I want to submit data using partail View.How do I do it? Can someone send simple sample code for understand it?
I want to create comment box as partail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your Html here, it would have been helpful.
I recommend that you use the ID of the `<input>` tag and SUBMIT the value of it to your server via ajax call.

```
var comments = $('#Comment_Box_ID').val();
  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/controller/method/',
        data: comments,
        success: function (data) {
           // success code
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // error code
        }
    });
```